# How to reference partner account info inside communities?

Tags: community, partner-communities

Is there anyway I can access or get reference to the partner account fields (or recordId) the partner user is associated with?

So what we want to do is, have a small section on the community page which displays the Partner Account Manager and his contact info. These are the two fields on the partner account. We want to display this so each partner user when logged in can see who his account manager (name) is and how to reach out to him (contact info).

Comment: The short answer to this is Yes. Have you tried anything so far, and if there is anything you are stuck with?

Comment: I'm very new to the community. I tried using Record Detail component but it asks for a record Id. I only need to get the reference to Account/Contact/User record, after that I can do possibly anything i.e. pass it to Lightning Component and display details in fancy way.